# What does ‘beyond in’ mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does ‘**beyond in**’ mean?

For example, ‘I served my time in the sixties as a block-layer **beyond in** Liverpool’.
Does it stand for ‘near Liverpool’? Or does the speaker just emphasize on the fact that it happened in the other city (not in the one he's staying now)?

Comment: https://youtu.be/ZBAijg5Betw

Comment: Could you tell us where you found this sentence, or did you make it up? It doesn't seem to make much sense, possibly it's a transcription error or simply an editing oversight.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @oerkelens No, I didn’t make it up. It’s from the book ‘The Spinning Heart’ by Donal Ryan. Maybe it is an Irish ruralism/dialect/slang. By the way, it is not for the first time that such construction is used in this book. Another example: “It’s only a shame he told no one he was mortgaging everything on the building of one last massive estate of houses that no one was going to buy and a share in some monstrosity beyond in Dubai.” 
I've found two more examples: “I heard one time that he came a cropper beyond in Liverpool, off of a motorbike”. “My daughters are beyond in England”.

Comment: Must be an informal Irish way of speaking. But “off of” is a modern abomination, from the US. Neither are British English regional expressions to my knowledge.

Comment: I wondered what a 'blocklayer' is; it seems to be an Irish word for a bricklayer, so I suspect the quote is in Irish dialect.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey A blocklayer can either be someone who builds walls from concrete or breeze (cinder?) blocks or someone who lays paving blocks. Having said that I think that "beyond in" is directly equivalent to "over there in" or possibly even "yonder in" and I agree that it sounds like Irish English to me.